# Pre-existing Items not Sortable when Connected to Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a settings page where users can drag items from a single list into any of three other lists to build content blocks on their website.  The single list is a jQuery Draggable and the three other lists are Sortables.  It basically looks like this.

```
<div class="sourceItems">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="destination"></div>
<div class="destination"></div>
<div class="destination"></div>
```

This is the jQuery.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.destination").sortable({
      revert: true,
      update: function (event, ui) {
        // Some code to prevent duplicates
      }
    });
    $("div.sourceItems").draggable({
      connectToSortable: '.destination',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      helper: 'clone',
      revert: 'invalid'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is, I have to load the previously-saved items into the three Sortable lists when the user goes back in to edit their settings.  Those items already in the Sortable when the page is loaded are not actually sortable.  Only items dragged from the Draggable are sortable.  How do I get the pre-existing items to also be sortable?

Comment: Try like it. Make a container div and apply sortable to it.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you make them lists or divs.  I have just used `li`s below as an example.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/LMGg8/

HTML:

```
<div>Draggable source items
    <ul>
        <li class="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Sortable List 1
    <ul class="sortableList">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Sortable List 2
    <ul class="sortableList">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Sortable List 3
    <ul class="sortableList">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
        revert: true,
        /*update: function (event, ui) {
            // Some code to prevent duplicates
        }*/
    });
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
});
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for your response.  Turns out it wasn't the format (i.e. div versus list) that mattered, because I changed your list items to divs and it still worked.  What you did do, however, was help demonstrate to me that it wasn't a "draggable connected to sortable" problem, so you freed my mind. The real problem was, when I loaded the saved items back into the sortable, I was giving them the same class to which I gave the original draggables.  So, they became draggables **inside** the sortable and didn't function like I expected.

Comment: Well for that I am glad! I have changed the first line of my answer to reflect that!